# Include Curly braces in Regular Expression to find C# Methods Definition

Tags: c#, .net, regex, methods, definition

Using this regular expression to find methods of C#. \w+(([^)]+))|\w+(()) with this I get the method name and parameters, I need to include the character "{" to be sure that is the definition of a method.
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txQmR.png)

Comment: Then add a `\s*?{` at the end of the expression to match the whitespace and the curly brace?

Comment: You cannot just append that to the pattern end, the alternatives should be placed inside a non-capturing group.

Comment: Finally, the pattern is (public|protected|internal|private)\s+?[\w+\s]+\w+\(([^)]+)\)|(public|protected|internal|private)\s+?[\w+\s]+\w+\(()\). In c# the brace is a break down when is the code formated. thks a lot!!!

Comment: Have you considered using the compiler objects to parse the code for you? You'll never handle all the formatting cases with a simple regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the pattern into a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) and then add `{`:

```
(?:\w+\(([^)]+)\)|\w+\(()\))[\p{Zs}\t]*{
^^^                        ^           ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG3bQ8/2)

Note that `[\p{Zs}\t]*` matches 0 or more horizontal whitespace symbols in .NET.

Also note that `{` does not have to be escaped in a .NET regex.

Comment: Note that you do not really have to use `()` to capture empty string. I kept it just in case you are using it somewhere in your code.

Comment: Also i want include  the modifier access.

Comment: Like [`(public|protected|internal|private)\s+\w+\s+(?:\w+\(([^)]+)\)|\w+\(()\))\p{Zs}*{`](https://regex101.com/r/iG3bQ8/3)?